# How to get to display images sized correctly in Outlook 2007?

Tags: html, css, outlook-2007

The width and height style attributes doesn't seem to work for Outlook 2007.

For example putting in `<img src="images/image003.jpg" style='width:49.5pt;height:169.5pt />` in a table cell doesn't affect the image size at all and the image occupies the whole table cell.

Comment: That is probably because of the `pt`. Try `px`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Outlook 2007 & 2010 don't handle inline styles consistently.  Change your img tag to read:

`<img src="images/image003.jpg" width="49.5" height="169.5" />`

Comment: Outlook has a lot of strange ways to handle HTML emails.  If you have any more problems, the first thing you should test is removing inline styles.  It may not be according to web standards but your success with Outlook will improve.